# C# Algorithm 'out'

Tags: c#

every time I try to compile this I get an error saying: 'Invalid expression term 'out'. Any ideas on what this means? Thanks.

```
using System;

class AlgorithmTest
{
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {

    int N = 5; 

        for (int i=1; i<=N; i=i+1){
        out.print(i);}
        for (int j=1; j<=N; j=j+1){
        out.print(j);}

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: you realize this is c# and not java, right?

Comment: Out is a keyword. Try Console.Write

Comment: What is `out` here by the way?

Comment: See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm confused now, why mention Java?

Comment: `System.Console.Write(i);`

Comment: @DonBoitnott, I know `out` but I was wondering what the developer was trying to do here.

Comment: Because Java has things like this:  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html

Comment: @Reece: because `out` is a method of the class `System` which returns a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) that has a method `print` in java.

Comment: Hey, why is this question tagged 'Algorithm'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [KIllercam says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28898027/284240) you need `Console.Writeline(string)`

```
int N = 5;

for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i + 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
for (int j = 1; j <= N; j = j + 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());
}


Console.ReadLine();
```

`Console.WriteLine()` will print in new line, if you want to print in one line without line break you can use `Console.Write()`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `System.Console.WriteLine` is not the equivalent to java's `System.out.print`. If he wants to print a new line he would have used [`out.println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()), so `Console.Write(i.ToString())` seems to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It means there that `out` is indeed an invalid expression, the compiler is right.

Try

```
Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, for once I think Visual Studio is spot on about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to the standard-output-stream use `Console.Out` instead:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("yourTextHere");
```

The `out` the compiler complains about is indeed a keyword which cannot be used for this purpose.